# VBA highlighting a cell if corresponding range in the same row is not blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I am trying to enforce food name in column B of a file if column D to DX (Qty) has any value in it.

Rational is if any new request of food is received which doesnt appear in the file, the user can temporarily type in the name of the food and then enter quantity. This is to ensure that operator dont enter a value by mistake or forget to convey information of the new item they added.

Is it possible to add a button, that could check for all the sheets from D6 to DX98 and if any quantity found and if then corresponding cell in C is empty is marks C as red and a simple MsgBox prompts that there is an error in the file.

The file I am working on is this:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00523976624440052148

Comment: Why use VBA? why not conditional formatting?

Comment: Let me check the conditional formatting. I just don't want users to be able to tamper with.

Answer (score 0):

Open Macros /Visual Basic, Double click on the sheet and insert this code on the right side:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim wksRange As Range
Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
Set wks = ActiveSheet
For i = 6 To 98 ' rows to be sweeped
    Set wksRange = wks.Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 127)) ' check from column 4 (D) to 127(DW)
    'Paint grey cells on columns A to C
    color_cell_a = Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color
    Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = color_cell_a
    Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = color_cell_a
    'If on the row there are values
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(wksRange) <> 0 Then
        itemName = Cells(i, 2)
        itemPrice = Cells(i, 3)
        'Change color on column B
        If itemName = "" Then
            Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(184, 0, 0)
        End If
        'Change color on column C
        If itemPrice = "" Then
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(184, 0, 0)
        End If
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

It checks the area covering `D6:DW98` and if there are a value on a row without *Item Name* and *Unit Price*, it will mark on red those cells until you write down anything on them.

The code is very easy to modify if you want to customize it.

Comment: Hi jcbermu, thanks a lot that worked great. I can use it. :)

Comment: Just a query to this, this row sweep - does it throw an error if cells to be tested for blank are protected?

Comment: I don't think so. However if you find problems because you have cells protected, insert this line: `wks.Protect "password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True` before the line `For i = 6 To 98`. Where *password* is the same password you're using to protect the worksheet.